# How do I extract data from Sitecore's Web Forms for Marketers database?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I want to be able to extract the form submissions from the Web Forms for marketers database and output it in an excel file I can make available to the public on demand.

Anyone know how I can do this?

I know they have an export to Excel option, but it is not automatic and requires someone to login and have access to the form.

I haven't been able to find any documentation from Sitecore on how to do this. Is this a supported operation? Do I have to reflect over the dlls to find api calls? Do I have to delve in to the SQL database and figure out how to do it manually? Is there no hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get lucky when using Reflector to disasamble the Sitecore.Forms dll. Try to find out if you can disassemble the code that get's run when clicking the Export button.

Actually:

The command comes from: `Sitecore.Form.Core.Commands.Export`

The executed code is in:  `Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.Export.Excel`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This writeup provides a very detailed account of how to do this if anyone else stumbles on this post. http://r-coding-sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/extracting-data-from-sitecore-wffm.html

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can use below given my blog URL to export data in CSV I have also written some blogs to export in XML and HTML on front end

http://sitecoretweaks.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/sitecore-export-to-csvexcel-of-web-form-for-marketers-form-wffm-reports/

You can find all blogs about export data
http://sitecoretweaks.wordpress.com/